# How to get tokens transferred in transaction details using web3 js?

Tags: javascript, web3js, bep20

I am using web3js to get transaction details

my code:

```
const transactionHash = this._req.query.transactionHash;

const transaction = await this._web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transactionHash);

const logs = await transaction.logs;

const log = await logs.find(i => i.transactionHash === transactionHash);

const topics = await log.topics;

const test = await this._web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter('bytes32', topics[0]);

const from = await this._web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter('address', topics[1]);

const to = await this._web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter('address', topics[2]);

const value = await this._web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter('uint256', log.data);

const amount = await this._web3.utils.fromWei(value);
```

But I still haven't got the token name of the transaction

[image]

Give me some suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the token symbol, you need to call the token contract's function `symbol()`.

Since the `Transfer` event was emitted by the token contract, you have its address in the `log.address` property. Then you just need to call the `symbol()` function:

```
const abiJson = [
    {"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}
];

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiJson, log.address);
const symbol = await contract.methods.symbol().call();
```